# How to change a property for a specified time? C#

Tags: c#, animation, pause

Hi I am trying to make a "flash animation" where the screen turns white for a fraction of a second, and then goes back to normal.

Here is my code:

```
private void QuickFallAnimation ()
    {
        plGame.BackColor = Color.White;
        Thread.Sleep(50);
        plGame.BackColor = Color.Black;
    }
```

The problem is that background-color never changes to white. It just stays black even though the rest of the application pauses for 50 milliseconds. Can anyone help?

Comment: What GUI are you using? `Thread.Sleep()` is almost never the right thing to do, let alone in an event handler.

Comment: You are not specifying the platform. What is `plGame`? 50 milliseconds is not a lot of time. It's probably almost imperceptible to the eye, even if it is in fact repainting.

Comment: Are you sure that the background doesn't change? Maybe it does but you have a lot of things going on on top of it that prevent you from showing it, but if that's not the case try to use a panel with background color white and set it `enabled=true` or `enabled=false` to mimic a white screen

Comment: If I change it to 1000 milliseconds nothing still happens. plGame is a panel property from windowsforms.

Comment: Is there any way to bypass this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the problem is that your putting your UI thread to sleep. While sleeping the UI is blocked and cannot do a re-render. **Never block the UI thread**.

changing the code to use async/await should fix the issue:

```
private async Task QuickFallAnimation ()
    {
        plGame.BackColor = Color.White;
        await Task.Delay(50);
        plGame.BackColor = Color.Black;
    }
```

You might also need to manually trigger a re-render, something like `plGame.Invalidate();`

The same could be done with a timer. Task.Delay is simply a wrapper around a timer that is sometimes convenient to use. But for more complex animations, a timer might be more appropriate.